# What made old Planeswalkers so powerful?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In *Magic: The Gathering*, Planeswalkers used to be incredibly powerful immortal beings before the Mending.

They were naturally extremely powerful after awakening, without needing to form numerous mana bonds or anything of the sort. My question is *what* made them so powerful? Where did the power come from?

I've heard that they had the ability to siphon mana directly from the Blind Eternities as opposed to filtering it through manabonds with lands. Did the Spark itself generate their mana? Something else entirely?

Comment: Wait, Magic actually has a _lore_ !?

Comment: @kalissar it has novels and everything (one per set of cards).

Comment: @Kalissar Most of the cards have lore right on them, and the card names, concepts, and pictures are based on the story for the set.

Answer (score 6):

Planeswalkers power does indeed seem to be related to their Spark. The Spark allows them to channel mana from multiple planes.

[From the MTG wiki](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Planeswalker%27s_spark)

> The first Magic novel, Arena depicted the spark as able to be
>   conceived through incredible amounts of mana being hoarded. A
>   different interpretation to reconcile Arena's depiction into
>   revisionist thought is; the planeswalkers had the spark all along and
>   the mana merely triggered it.

---

> More recent material indicate that the spark is what allows
>   planeswalkers to use mana from multiple planes; should a spark be
>   lost, inactive or defective, they are only able to use mana from the
>   plane they are on.